# Proper use of MySQL JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I've never used JOIN before, so I'm having trouble how to properly make the MySQL query using PHP.

I have a table named `store` with rows itemid, prices, etc. I also have a table named `item_list` with rows id, attributes, etc. .

I want to be able to access 'store' itemid's and using those, access `item_list` id's and the that id's attributes. I came up with a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT store.price, item_list.*  
            FROM store, item_list 
           WHERE item_list.id = store.itemid";
```

I get an error when I try to execute the query. Any suggestions?

Comment: The easier to read, the easier to help you.  Funny that you can edit the question, but fail to mention the specific error you're getting.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's not a MYSQL error, but the query just does not execute. I use if statement:  if (!$result = $mysqli->conn($query)) { return $error; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT store.price, item_list.*  
            FROM store LEFT JOIN item_list ON item_list.id = store.itemid
```

Also you should be explicit about which columns you are selecting, rather than the *. This is for safety and performance.

Another nice feature is table aliases, which make your SQL a little less verbose:

```
$query = "SELECT s.price, il.col1, il.col2, il.col3  
            FROM store s LEFT JOIN item_list il ON s.itemid = il.id
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code worked. I'll try to incorporate the use of table aliases as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo. It should be

```
WHERE item_list.id = store.itemid
```

you have

```
WHERE item.id =
```

Comment: in the WHERE clause, "item" is not a valid table. They are "store" and "item_list"

Answer (score 0):

If you wanz zo exclude all rows in both tables with NULL values then you want to use a INNER JOIN. A LEFT JOIN exclude only rows with NULL values on the left side of the join.

```
$query = "SELECT store.price, item_list.*  
        FROM store INNER JOIN item_list ON item_list.id = store.itemid
```